# html element creates unexplained white spacing

Tags: html, css, background

I have a simple website with a fixed background image.
I want it to stay right there and everything else just should scroll over it.
At the bottom I have a navbar. A simple div container with a border and an inline-block list in it. So I have my full sized background image in the background that fills the whole screen and my content on it. When I start scrolling the content starts to move up and should make place for the upcoming navbar but at the bottom a white space appears.

not scrolled:

[image]

when scrolled: (open pic on  imgur to view the white space)

[image]

The background stays where it is but when I scroll it kinda "pulls up" the white space. But there shouldn't be anything right? Has this something to do with a margin?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="mainDiv">
<div class="opener">
    <img src="header.svg" alt="" width="30%">
</div>
<div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.svg" alt="">
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Start</li>
        <li>Tracks</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
height: 100%;
}

p {
margin: 0;
}

.mainDiv {
background-image: url(main_background.png);
background-color:#707070;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position:center;
height: 100%;
}

.opener {
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 4%;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}

.logo {
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 50px;
width: 30%;
}

nav {
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 40px;
width: 30%;
border-style: solid;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 5px;
}

ul {
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

li {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
margin-right: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
}

li:hover {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Thanks for reading and the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your background is fixed in your .mainDiv class, but the mainDiv element itself isn't fixed, so it is scrolling.

You could put the background in the html, body class
or you could add `position: fixed` to the mainDiv class.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that out. Thanks, that fixed it perfectly! :)